# Why can't I retrieve deleted DevExpress Grid rows?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I'm trying to get a list of rows deleted by pressing the '-' button in a Devexpress Grid widget as depicted [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#InterfaceElementsWin/CustomDocument4568).
However, doing the following does not return any results

```
 DataView delrows = new DataView(myTableAdapter.DataView.Table);
 delrows.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.Deleted;
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit: Filtering on Added and Modified rows works fine.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing as you do now try this:

```
myTableAdapter.DataView.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.Deleted;
```

of course it's not easy to guess without knowing better your data binding architecture...

Comment: That doesn't work either (also I need to partition Added, Modified and Deleted rows).

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your DevExpress grid is binded to a DataTable (either with or without a DataView):

You can retrieve the deleted rows by using the `Select()` method of the `DataTable`. This is not a linq method.

```
table.Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.Deleted);
```

The rest of the rows can be retrieved by using

```
table.Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Just be aware that a row that is added then deleted will not have the deleted flag, but will instead be removed from the rows collection. Such rows would also have a `RowState` of `Detached`.

Comment: That query is returning zero rows for me.

Comment: Like I said, if these rows were added before any `AcceptChanges` were called, these rows won't be returned, since they are not deleted, but rather removed

Comment: This isn't a row that was added then deleted. I'm not calling AcceptChanges explicitly.

Comment: Is there any way to debug this or to add a handler on the '-' button press?

Comment: Yes, place a handler on the embedded navigator: `grid.EmbeddedNavigator.ButtonClick += new DevExpress.XtraEditors.NavigatorButtonClickEventHandler(EmbeddedNavigator_ButtonClick);`

Comment: The row seems to be deleted from the table before the handler is invoked.